# How do I use this new listener

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm developing a turnbased multiplayer android app.

Initially, I had to implement `TurnBasedMultiplayerListener` and override `onTurnBasedMatchInitiated` but now the interface is deprecated and I need to use [this listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult.html)

The problem is, I dont know how to use it. I have made my class implement the interface, and I have overridden the methods.

I then create a turnBasedGame As follows...

```
PendingResult<InitiateMatchResult> f =
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(gApiClient, tbmc);
```

And now I think I have to say `f.setResultCallback(...)`but I dont know what to put inside it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to give a class which implemented ResultCallback as a parameter.

```
public void MatchInitiatedCallback implements ResultCallback {

    @Override
    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
        // Check if the status code is not success;
        if (result.getStatus != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            showError(statusCode);
            return;
        }

        TurnBasedMatch match = result.getMatch();

        // If this player is not the first player in this match, continue.
        if (match.getData() != null) {
            showTurnUI(match);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, this is the first player. Initialize the game state.
        initGame(match);

        // Let the player take the first turn
        showTurnUI(match);
    }
}
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#selecting_players_with_the_default_user_interface

Comment: I've tried that before. It says void is an invalid type for MatchInitiatedCallback